# Spatial index for geo coordinates?

Tags: data-structures, indexing, geospatial

What kind of data structure could be used for an efficient nearest neighbor search in a large set of geo coordinates? With "regular" spatial index structures like R-Trees that assume planar coordinates, I see two problems (Are there others I have overlooked?):

- Wraparound at the poles and the International Date Line
- Distortion of distances near the poles

How can these factors be allowed for? I guess the second one could compensated by transforming the coordinates. Can an R-Tree be modified to take wraparound into account? Or are there specialized geo-spatial index structures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Geohash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash).

Also, to compensate for wraparound, simply use not one but three orthogonal R-trees, so that there does not exist a point on the earth surface such that all three trees have a wraparound at that point. Then, two points are close if they are close according to at least one of these trees.

Comment: Geohash seems to be a "works pretty well most of the time" kind of thing, but cannot be relied on to always provide a common prefix for nearby locations. However, the idea of using several R-Trees looks like a good solution for the wraparound problem.

Answer (score 3):

Could you use a locality-sensitive hashing (LSH) algorithm in 3 dimensions?  That would quickly give you an approximate neighboring group which you could then sanity-check by calculating great-circle distances.

[Here's a paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/5q1q135314382494/) describing an algorithm for efficient LSH on the surface of a unit *d*-dimensional hypersphere.  Presumably it works for *d*=3.